# Get subset of string using ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

my data has two simple columns, the first column is a string consisting of "/" as delimiter. I want to explode the string and get the second item. I could achieve it using INDEX and SPLIT formulas. How can I rewrite this operation using ARRAYFORMULA?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A, "/"),,2)
```

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A, "/"),,2))

Comment: @Salar you dont need AF wrapping. index is type of AF